# Web api call another web api where save the token and refresh this after expiration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api that use an other web api, but there are an authentification between with token.
How to save a token and manage refresh token if web api should be stateless.

I can use static or memeorycache but this is not stateless.

Comment: It's a security threat be secure tokens stored. Instead regenerate a new token based on the established identity of the incoming Api call. HTH

Comment: I want store token between two http request